# CSV is not getting generated in the folder for console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, console-application

I want to generate a CSV file in my folder with the data coming from `datatable`. I have written the below code for that.

```
public static void CreateCSV(DataTable dt, string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            string strFilePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ExcelFilePath"].ToString() + "\\" + FileName;
            if (!Directory.Exists(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ExcelFilePath"].ToString()))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ExcelFilePath"].ToString());
            
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
            DataTable dTemp = dt;
            
            int iColCount = dTemp.Columns.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dTemp.Columns[i]);
                if (i < iColCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dTemp.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                    {

                        if (dr[i].ToString().Contains("\n"))
                        {
                            string x = dr[i].ToString().Replace("\n", "");
                            string xc = RemoveSpecialCharacters(x);
                            string xc1 = RemoveSpecialCharacters1(xc);
                            //sw.Write(x);
                            sw.Write(xc1.Replace(", ", ""));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string x = dr[i].ToString().Replace(",", "");
                            string xc = RemoveSpecialCharacters(x);
                            string xc1 = RemoveSpecialCharacters1(xc);                                
                            sw.Write(xc1.Replace(", ", ""));                               
                        }
                    }
                    if (i < iColCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(",");
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }
            sw.Close();               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ErrorLog.Insert(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "Program.cs - MailReport", null);
        }
    }
```

And the folder path which I have set in `app.config` file is below:

`<add key="ExcelFilePath" value="ExcelData" />`

but still the CSV file is not getting created. Am I missing something?

Comment: what's strFilePath's value when you debug it?

Comment: @qxg: the value is `ExcelData\Generated_File_Record.csv`

Comment: Works for me with ExcelFilePath = C:\temp and FileName = test.csv, ignoring RemoveSpecialCharacters as I don't know how you implementation looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have a relative path not an absolute one. You need an absolute one.

Use

`strFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ExcelFilePath"].ToString(), FileName);`

and

`Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ExcelFilePath"].ToString()));`

to create the directory. No need to check if directory exists, CreateDirectory will only try to create it if it does not exist.